# Join a tablas de diferentes servidores Sql Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

Quiero saber si se puede hacer JOIN a tablas de diferentes servidores, lo intenté de esta manera pero me lanza un error.
Uso Registered Servers

> Reference to database and/or server name is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

```html
select * 
from [server1].[BD1].[ErrorLog] E
left join [server2].[BD1].[Request] R ON E.Id=R.Id
where E.Id='123'
```

Comment: ¿Y qué dice la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#join-tables-from-a-linked-server)? Allí dice cómo debes hacerlo y las versiones de SQL Server que lo soportan. Tal parece que la tuya no es soportada.

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes si ejecutas `SELECT @@VERSION`? Pregunto porque lo que pides sí se puede, pero puede tener restricción por la edición que uses.